# Javascript loaded with ajax only works the first time

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I've created two simple testpages. One loads the other one using XMLHttpRequest. (just a page using slimbox to display a image)
This works perfect the first time. But when trying to run it again, by pressing the button again, it does not work anymore. When I reload the whole page, it works the first time again. Do I have to un-load or re-load the scripts or something?
I know It is double of the script-tags here, don't know why but its the only way I got it to work in the first place. How come it only works the first time?

Please help.

testajax.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="SlimBox/css/slimbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"   />


<script id="script1" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
<script id="script2" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="SlimBox/js/mootools.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="SlimBox/js/slimbox.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(Page)
{
 var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
   document.getElementById("myDivFull").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   document.getElementById('script1').src = 'SlimBox/js/mootools.js';
   document.getElementById('script2').src = 'SlimBox/js/slimbox.js';
  }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET",Page,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="Header2" type="button" onClick="loadXMLDoc('testImage.php')" name='Sok' value='Load' >            
   <div id="myDivFull"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

testImage.php

```
<a href='img/facebook-icon.png' rel='lightbox' cap='test'><img alt='' border='0' src='img/facebook-icon.png' /></a>
```

**EDIT:**
The method provided by gilly3 worked perfectly with the seperate js file, however I can not get it to work if I add a google gadget script 'link' into the function. Is this solved in a different way maybe? Below is the code I can not get to work.

```
function addScript(src)
{
    var script = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script"));
    script.src = src;
} 

if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    document.getElementById("myDivFull").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    addScript('//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.mortgage-info.com/gadgets    
    /gadgetsmortgagecalculator.xml&amp;synd=open&amp;w=250&amp;h=200& 
    amp;title=Mortgage+Calculator&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&
    amp;output=js');
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried adding a nonce parameter to the end of the script URLs?

Comment: why are you re-loading the javascript files? I'm sure there are better ways to do thi.

Comment: probably better ways... any suggestions? thank you

Comment: A "nonce" is a dummy parameter added to the URL, with a non-repeating value (like the current timestamp or something).  Just add "?x=" and the timestamp to the end of the script URLs and see if that helps. It might not; I'm not sure how browsers respond to script URL property changes.

Comment: Did you check xmlhttp.readyState and xmlhttp.status both times?

Comment: you aren't likely to get much help reusing an old question for a new issue.  Please start a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9566099/1149557

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely there's a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do.  But, I don't know what you are trying to do, and there *is* a simple answer to your question:

Don't bother with creating the empty script tags.  Just add as many script tags as you like dynamically:

```
function addScript(src)
{
    var script = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script"));
    script.src = src;
}

if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    document.getElementById("myDivFull").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    addScript('SlimBox/js/mootools.js');
    addScript('SlimBox/js/slimbox.js');
}
```

**Edit:** The "better way" would be to create a function that does what you want, and call it whenever you need to.  Eg, if your script contained:

```
someArray = window.someArray || [];
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".someClass");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    someArray.push(elements[i].value);
}
```

You would just create a function:

```
var someArray = [];
function reInit()
{
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".someClass");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        someArray.push(elements[i].value);
    }
}
```

Then call it each time you receive your AJAX data.

Comment: yess!!.. thank you!!! Imagine something that simple, just made my day. Your a genious. Thanks.

Comment: Hey gilly3... how come it does not work if I insert a script for a google gadget into the "addscript" function? like this..        addScript('//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.mortgage-info.com/gadgets/gadgetsmortgagecalculator.xml&amp;synd=open&amp;w=250&amp;h=200&amp;title=Mortgage+Calculator&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js');