# Javascript link loaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

With ajax I use the below function 'addScript' to add a js file to the loaded page. This works just fine with

```
addScript('SlimBox/js/mootools.js');
```

however I can not get it to work if I add a google gadget script 'link' into the function. Is this solved in a different way maybe? Below is the code I can not get to work.

```
function addScript(src)
{
    var script = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script"));
    script.src = src;
} 

...
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
   document.getElementById("myDivFull").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

   addScript('//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.mortgage-info.com/gadgets    
   /gadgetsmortgagecalculator.xml&amp;synd=open&amp;w=250&amp;h=200& 
   amp;title=Mortgage+Calculator&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&
   amp;output=js');
}
```

Thank you. See original question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8948846/1149557

Comment: I'd just use an iframe to embed that mortgage calculator into your page.

Comment: Why you are not using Jquery I do not know - however, have you properly escaped out your URL?  Maybe.... addScript('\/\/www.gmodules.com\/ig\/ifr?url=http:\/\/www.mortgage-info.com\/gadgets\/gadgetsmortgagecalculator.xml&amp;synd=open&amp;w=250&amp;h=200&amp;title=Mortgage+Calculator&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js')

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are loading returns HTML, not JavaScript.  This seems to be because you are using `&amp;` instead of just `&`. Replace `&amp;` with `&` and that should solve your problem:

```
addScript("//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.mortgage-info.com/gadgets" +
    "/gadgetsmortgagecalculator.xml&synd=open&w=250&h=200&title=Mortgage+Calculator" +
    "&border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&output=js");
```

Comment: Hello again gilly3, thank you for helping with my "stupid" questions. Did not get it to work with replacing &amp; but works with iframe as mentioned above, so just using that for now.